# Arduino, problem with displaying RFID ID

Tags: arduino, rfid, parallax

I have recently gotten a Parallax RFID reader and I was trying to make it work with my Arduino uno. I have gotten all the necessary wires attached and I used a RFID reading program I found from Make (I will put the code at the bottom). When I open serial monitor and move an RFID card near it, it spits a series of x's and ø's(eg. xxxxøxxxxøxxøø). I am expecting to see a combination of letters and numbers. I think its a problem with the code, but I dont know enough about it to know whats wrong.

The code can be found at http://cdn.makezine.com/make/28/RFIDread.pde

The RFID reader can be found here http://www.parallax.com/Store/Microcontrollers/BASICStampModules/tabid/134/txtSearch/rfid/List/1/ProductID/114/Default.aspx?SortField=ProductName%2cProductName

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Hex has characters from 0 to F, there are no x's involved. If you are using a serial monitor it's probably interpreting the bytes as ASCII (you may be able to set it to hex/binary/etc format also) If you post exactly what you are getting it may help. Also a link to the RFID reader in question would be useful.

Comment: Something odd about that code, it seems to assume the reader rather than the PC is connected to the arduino's serial in, but the PC still connected to the serial out - possible I guess, but unusual.  Anyway, do you have the serial monitor set to 2400 baud?  Do you see the "RFID tag is: " string or just the x's and 0's ?

Comment: Baud rate problem?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tried changing the baud rate of the serial monitor and that seemed to work! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, serial monitor baud rate must match the 2400 baud used by the sketch.